# Autoplay inlined youtube video on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, youtube, uiwebview

I need to autoplay an inlined video from youtube in uiwebview with IOS 5.0+.
I managed to make it play inlined with this:

```
   NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
             <html>\
             <head>\
             <script type='text/javascript'>\
                  function onPlayerReady(event) {\
                  event.target.playVideo();\
                  }\
            </script>\
             <style type=\"text/css\">\
             iframe {position:absolute; top:0%%; margin-top:-0px;}\
             body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}\
             </style>\
             </head>\
             <body>\
             <iframe width=\"100%%\"  src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?feature=player_detailpage& modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0;autoplay=1;showinfo=0;loop=1;autohide=1;playsinline=1;autoplay=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
             </body>\
             </html>", ID];
   [videoWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

But i cant figure out how to make it auto play.
I also found other solution which auto plays the video but it starts in fullscreen, and i dont know how to make it inlined.

```
    NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>body{margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;}</style></head> 
<body> <div id=\"player\"></div> 
    <script> var tag = document.createElement('script'); 
    tag.src = \"http://www.youtube.com/player_api\"; 
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); 
    var player; 
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { 
        player = new YT.Player('player', {width:'%d', height: '%d', videoId:'%@', events: { 'onReady': onPlayerReady, } }); } 
        function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo(); } 
    </script> 
</body> </html>";

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML, 320, 150, ID];
    [videoWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

Is there a way to make js version inlined or first version autoplay? Or is there some other solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found it.
In JS version you can specify player parameters (like "showinfo", "rel" and of course "playsinline" )

You just need to add `playerVars` object and specify your parameters in it.
So the code would look like this:

```
NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>body{margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;}</style></head> <body> <div id=\"player\"></div> <script> var tag = document.createElement('script'); tag.src = \"http://www.youtube.com/player_api\"; var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); var player; function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { player = new YT.Player('player', {width:'%d', height: '%d', videoId:'%@', playerVars: {'playsinline' : 1, 'rel':0, 'showinfo':0}, events: { 'onReady': onPlayerReady, } }); } function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo(); } </script> </body> </html>";

NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML, 320, 180, ID];
[videoWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using native Video Player?
Try [LBYouTubeView](https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView) wrapper, it is very easy to integrate.

Comment: because i think it is against youtube rules